# Create new element with button and have content 'Table' | JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here I will create a 'Third tab' using the button, when the Create Button has been clicked, the 'Third Tab' will appear in the .tab class and when 'The third tab' is clicked, there is a datatable in it.

So, the conclusion.
**How to create a div class and contain a datatable with button?**.

Here we go : [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oqnLhbes/)

Snippet: (**JQUERY, HTML, JAVASCRIPT, CSS**)

**Error Message :** *"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null"* | Line 40.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tabel_audience').DataTable({}); // datatable
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.submitButton').click(function () {
    var tab = '<button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, \'thirdTab\')" id="default">Third Tab</button>';  
    var content = '<div id="mainTab" class="tabcontent">' +
  '<table class="tabel_audience" class="table table-bordered" cellspacing="0">' +
    '<thead>' +
      '<tr>' +
        '<th style="border-color:rgb(221, 221, 221);">' +
          '<input name="select_all" value="1" id="selectAll" type="checkbox" />' +
        '</th>' +
        '<th>Name</th>' +
        '<th>Type</th>' +
        '<th>Size</th>' +
      '</tr>' +
    '</thead>' +
  '</table>' +
'</div>';
  $('.tab').append(tab);
  $('.bodycontent').append(content);
  });
});
```

```css
    .submitButton {
      
      font-variant: petite-caps;
      border: 0px;
      color: #fff;
      text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1); 
      background-color: #4d90fe;
      padding: 17px 0px;
      font-family: Quicksand;
      font-size: 14px;
      width: 290px;
      

    }

    .submitButton:hover {

      border: 0px;
      text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
      background-color: #357ae8;

    }
    body {
      font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
    }
    /* Style the tab */
    div.tab {
      overflow: hidden;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
    }

    /* Style the buttons inside the tab */

    div.tab button {
      background-color: inherit;
      float: left;
      border: none;
      outline: none;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      transition: 0.3s;
      font-size: 17px;
    }

    /* Change background color of buttons on hover */

    div.tab button:hover {
      background-color: #ddd;
    }

    /* Create an active/current tablink class */

    div.tab button.active {
      background-color: #ccc;
    }

    /* Style the tab content */

    .tabcontent {
      display: none;
      padding: 6px 12px;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      border-top: none;
    }
```

```html
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>


    <!-- TABS NAVIGATION -->
    <div class="tab">
    <!-- THIS IS CREATE BUTTON-->
    <input type="button" class="submitButton" id="submitButton" value="Create" style="width:142px;margin-left: 150px;">

    <!-- THIS IS TAB BUTTON-->
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'mainTab')" id="default">Main Tab</button>
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'secondTab')">Second Tab</button>
      
    </div>
    <!-- END of TABS BUTTON -->

    <!-- TABS CONTENT -->
    <div class="bodycontent">
    <div id="mainTab" class="tabcontent">
      <table class="tabel_audience" class="table table-bordered" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th style="border-color:rgb(221, 221, 221);">
              <input name="select_all" value="1" id="selectAll" type="checkbox" />
            </th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Size</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      </table>
    </div>

    <div id="secondTab" class="tabcontent">
      <table class="tabel_audience" class="table table-bordered" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th style="border-color:rgb(221, 221, 221);">
              <input name="select_all" value="1" id="selectAll" type="checkbox" />
            </th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Type</th>

          </tr>
        </thead>
      </table>
    </div>

    </div> 
    <!-- END of TABS CONTENT -->
    <script>
      function openTab(event, TabName) {
        var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
        tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
        for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
          tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
        for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
          tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
        document.getElementById(TabName).style.display = "block";
        event.currentTarget.className += " active";
      }
      document.getElementById("default").click();

    </script>
```

Original Code  : [W3Shcools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_tabs)

Image My Project [Here](https://prnt.sc/h75c33)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to correct the name of the new tab to `thirdTab` instead of `mainTab` as it is currently set in the statement `<div id="mainTab" class="tabcontent">`. Change this to `<div id="thirdTab" class="tabcontent">` to make it work.

I didn't look at the code why the whole table isn't showing up. Let me know if you're unable to get that right.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tabel_audience').DataTable({}); // datatable
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.submitButton').click(function () {
    var tab = '<button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, \'thirdTab\')" id="thirdTabButton">Third Tab</button>';  
    var content = '<div id="thirdTab" class="tabcontent">' +
  '<table class="tabel_audience" class="table table-bordered" cellspacing="0">' +
    '<thead>' +
      '<tr>' +
        '<th style="border-color:rgb(221, 221, 221);">' +
          '<input name="select_all" value="1" id="selectAll" type="checkbox" />' +
        '</th>' +
        '<th>Name</th>' +
        '<th>Type</th>' +
        '<th>Size</th>' +
      '</tr>' +
    '</thead>' +
  '</table>' +
'</div>';
  $('.tab').append(tab);
  $('.bodycontent').append(content);
  });
});
```

```css
    .submitButton {
      
      font-variant: petite-caps;
      border: 0px;
      color: #fff;
      text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1); 
      background-color: #4d90fe;
      padding: 17px 0px;
      font-family: Quicksand;
      font-size: 14px;
      width: 290px;
      

    }

    .submitButton:hover {

      border: 0px;
      text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
      background-color: #357ae8;

    }
    body {
      font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
    }
    /* Style the tab */
    div.tab {
      overflow: hidden;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
    }

    /* Style the buttons inside the tab */

    div.tab button {
      background-color: inherit;
      float: left;
      border: none;
      outline: none;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      transition: 0.3s;
      font-size: 17px;
    }

    /* Change background color of buttons on hover */

    div.tab button:hover {
      background-color: #ddd;
    }

    /* Create an active/current tablink class */

    div.tab button.active {
      background-color: #ccc;
    }

    /* Style the tab content */

    .tabcontent {
      display: none;
      padding: 6px 12px;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      border-top: none;
    }
```

```html
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>


    <!-- TABS NAVIGATION -->
    <div class="tab">
    <!-- THIS IS CREATE BUTTON-->
    <input type="button" class="submitButton" id="submitButton" value="Create" style="width:142px;margin-left: 150px;">

    <!-- THIS IS TAB BUTTON-->
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'mainTab')" id="default">Main Tab</button>
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'secondTab')">Second Tab</button>
      
    </div>
    <!-- END of TABS BUTTON -->

    <!-- TABS CONTENT -->
    <div class="bodycontent">
    <div id="mainTab" class="tabcontent">
      <table class="tabel_audience" class="table table-bordered" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th style="border-color:rgb(221, 221, 221);">
              <input name="select_all" value="1" id="selectAll" type="checkbox" />
            </th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Size</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      </table>
    </div>

    <div id="secondTab" class="tabcontent">
      <table class="tabel_audience" class="table table-bordered" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th style="border-color:rgb(221, 221, 221);">
              <input name="select_all" value="1" id="selectAll" type="checkbox" />
            </th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Type</th>

          </tr>
        </thead>
      </table>
    </div>

    </div> 
    <!-- END of TABS CONTENT -->
    <script>
      function openTab(event, TabName) {
        var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
        tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
        for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
          tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
        for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
          tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
        document.getElementById(TabName).style.display = "block";
        event.currentTarget.className += " active";
      }
      document.getElementById("default").click();

    </script>
```

Comment: Sorry... \'thirdTab\' not work? or cant call variable 'content' ?

Comment: Can you update your code in the jsFiddle or in your question above? I can have a look at it.

Comment: Updated : https://jsfiddle.net/oqnLhbes/2/  . i try to call thirdTab in openTab() but unsolved.

Comment: I can see that you've got the tab working. Now, do you want a similar table to appear in the third tab as in the other tabs?

Comment: Sure, there is still a problem in calling ID on the function, because I use single quote to use html script.

Comment: We just need to run the `$().DataTable()` on the content of the thirdTab - I have updated your fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/oqnLhbes/4/). That fixes your problem.If you have any other issue, leave me a message - I'll be able to look at it tomorrow; I need to go right now. Have a great evening.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158378/discussion-between-calvin-ananda-and-yatin).

Answer (score 0):

write `thirdTab` instead of `maintab` in `div id` so it will work

```
var content = '<div id="mainTab" class="tabcontent">Third tab' +
  '<table class="tabel_audience" class="table table-bordered" cellspacing="0">' +
    '<thead>' +
      '<tr>' +
        '<th style="border-color:rgb(221, 221, 221);">' +
          '<input name="select_all" value="1" id="selectAll" type="checkbox" />' +
        '</th>' +
        '<th>Name</th>' +
        '<th>Type</th>' +
        '<th>Size</th>' +
      '</tr>' +
    '</thead>' +
  '</table>' +
'</div>';
```

Comment: Not work dude, i think failed to create \'thirdTab\' id in openTab function. any help?

Comment: so you display `thirdtab`